# How to re-structure OOPs code with multiple subclasses to avoid downcasting?

Tags: oop, inheritance, casting

I am having with doubts regarding structuring of a code which involves multiple classes.
I have multiple services like `ServiceX`,`ServiceY` and so on. Now all the services has certain code data members (variables) which are common. So what I thought is to create a separate class `Common` which will contain common data and all the service class can extend it.

```
public class Common{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  public int getA()
  public int getB()
  public int getC()
}
```

```
public class ServiceX extends Common{
  int x1;
  int x2;
  int x3;

  public int getX1()
  public int getX2()
  public int getX3()
}
```

But now, I have some interface `HandleService`

```
public interface HandleService{
  public String foo(Common comm);
}
```

This interface is implemented by services to do something and want their specific service data memebers. For example:

```
public class HandleServiceX implements HandleService{
  @Override
  public String foo(Common comm){
  // Here I want both Common and ServiceX data members also i.e. a,b,c,x1,x2,x3.
}
```

```
Main(){
  // Here I have to handle all the services. For example: 
  HandleService serv = new HandleServiceX(); // Handling service X
  serv.foo(new ServiceX());
}
```

Although I have passed ServiceX object in the function though I cannot access its members without downcasting. Otherwise, I have to downcast to all the HandleService Types to their respective service.
Is there any possible way to avoid downcasting here? Or Maybe some restructuring of full code to do it more better and efficient way?

If I go with downcasting thing, I am not sure if it is a good practice?

Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to create an overloaded method that would accept the subtype, in that way you avoid downcasting.